# VirtualHost on Apache2 gives no response

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I'm trying to create a virtual host on apache2 but I am getting no response. I have tried serveral tutorials but nothing has helped. This is my file:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName  androidwebservice.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/my_webservice/public"
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine_error.log
CustomLog /var/www/my_webservice/android_access.log combined

<Directory "/var/www/my_webservice/">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
RailsEnv production
RailsBaseURI /my_webservice
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I have enabled it using the command sudo a2ensite androidbackend(this is the file name). The file is located in /etc/apache2/sites-available.

The ServerName has been declared in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.1.1 androidwebservice.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you visiting androidwebservice.com or www.androidwebservice.com
Because you have declared androidwebservice.com not www.androidwebservice.com

The basic (working) example is over here:

https://reformatcode.com

Comment: i am visiting androidwebservice.com